# calling php function from another file

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am a PHP beginner and trying to write PHP classes that work with HTML and MySql.
I am facing the following problem,
I have created a class called DatabaseManager that contains the function get_value. This function simply returns a value. In another file, I am calling this function on a button click using java script. But the link doesn't seem to work between the two files....Can someone help me?
thank you.

Here's my file that contains the PHP class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

class DatabaseManager {

private $value=1;


    public function get_value ()
    {   
    return value;
    }


}

/php>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the other file that calls it.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include("DatabaseManager.php"); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function connect()
{

<?php

$database_manager= new DatabaseManager;
echo "the value is" . $database_manager->get_value();

?>
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" value="Search " onclick="connect()">


</body>
</html>
```

The name of the file that contains the function get_value is DatabaseManager.php

Comment: Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Including the file will include everything, so you're going to end up with **everything**. This will result in two sets of nested `<html><head>etc` tags

Comment: just a side note as I look this over, you don't need the HTML in the class...

Comment: Does your php class include file need all the html element? I would try first remove all of those for sanity's sake.

Comment: In your calling file, You've got PHP code inside of script tags, but no script. Your result here is `<script>function(connect){Your value is _value_ }</script>`

Comment: Thanks guys, I will consider your recommendations.
@Paul, so can i remove all the tags in the called class?

Comment: @cpilko, what's the right way then?

Comment: @TravelingSalesman - See my answer below. I'm adding to it as I notice new issues ;)

Comment: @TravelingSalesman: You should edit your question and tell us what you are trying to do with this script. E.g: Why do you need the javascript button to update your page, and how are you passing the value to query to your database.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but you should read a good intro to PHP book. There are so many things wrong with this as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

DO Like  this

In Databasemanager.php

```
<?php
    class DatabaseManager {    
    private $value = 1;

       public function get_value() {    
            return $this->value;
        }    
    }

    ?>
```

In another PHP file

```
<html>
<head>
<?php include("Databasemanager.php"); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function connect()
{
<?php
$database_manager= new DatabaseManager;
echo "the value is" . $database_manager->get_value();
?>
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" value="Search " onclick="connect()"> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. in `DatabaseManager.php` remove all HTML. You're including the file elsewhere, you don't need or want duplicated HTML tags.
2. Remove the `@` in your MySQL section. This suppresses any errors you are having.
3. Switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). They are safer (if used properly)
4. Your closing php tag is wrong in the database file. You have `/php>` it should be `?>`
5. Your class does absolutely nothing as-is.

Comment: Quick note though as per point #4 - in 'pure' php files, skip closing tag completely.

Answer (score 0):

You do it wrong way, to output something in your JavaScript function connect() make this  :

```
     function connect() {
        alert("
     <?php    
           $database_manager= new DatabaseManager;
            echo "the value is" . $database_manager->get_value();     
       ?>
        ");
    }
```

because php code is executed apart from your on click event.
Actually it's unclear what you wish to get, but you misunderstand the basics.

[edited to clarify users question how to output something to the screen]

Comment: divide by zero, I just want to make sure that the link between the two files is working okay. Therefore, i need to echo something on the screen on the click of the button that indicates the success....Can you provide me with an example? I don't see that sentence when I click the button.

Comment: sure you don't see, because the JS function to output something to your screen isn't called...i will edit my answer so you can see hot to alert something.

Comment: divide by zero,
I tried to do this alert ("hi"); 
it worked fine.
but        alert("
     <?php    
            $database_manager= new DatabaseManager;
            echo "the value is" . $database_manager->get_value();     
       ?>
        ");
did not work with me.

Comment: rework your function in class databaseManager to
`public function get_value ()
    {   
    return $this->value;
    }`

Comment: I did that as well,
I actually noticed that when I embed any php code in java script function it does not work...I believe there is something wrong with php server....Do you know What's possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things here that you're douing wrong.

1. You don't need the html code in the first example.
2. You close the php wrong `/php>` should generate an error, it should be `?>`
3. When your instantiating your DatabaseManager class you've left out the parentheses which means that the constructor will never get called, this should also generate an error.
4. You're probably trying to use alert in javascript which in this case you're not doing.

It should look something like this instead:

```
<?php
class DatabaseManager {
private $value = 1;

    function getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }

}

?>
```

And in your html (still php, but the one containing the html-markup) file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function connect() {
        alert("
        <?php
            include "nameofDBManagerClassFile.php"
            $dbm = new DatabaseManager();
            echo "the value is " . $dbm->getValue();
        ?>
        ");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It could also be that you think that the php-code that is inside of the javascript function will not be executed untill you call the JS function connect() this is not so. PHP code is executed on the server and thus will be called when a user requests that webpage, the javascript on the other hand is clientside and will be executed in the users browser. I highly recommend that you read up on both php and JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel,
does this work?

<?php

$database_manager= new DatabaseManager();
alert( $database_manager->get_value());
?>

Comment: You still have to encapsultate the php-statement in quotes. like this: alert("<?php ..code here.. ?>");

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use require i another file.

```
require('login.php');

function get_value()
{
return get_value;
}
```